# LinearLayout inside AlertDialog Not Scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-alertdialog

I have set a linear layout inside a alert dialog in which I basically have a few Edit texts.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to scroll down to see every edit text created dynamically.

Here's the snippet:

```
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        LinearLayout layoutCreateMerch = new LinearLayout(context);
        layoutCreateMerch.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layoutCreateMerch.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Act.this);
        alert.setTitle("Submit");
        final EditText Name = new EditText(Act.this);
        final EditText Desc = new EditText(Act.this);
...
...
```

So, How can I add a scroll view at runtime in this alert dialog's Linear Layout?

I suppose LinearLayouts don't need a scroll bar/view but this isn't working out for me :|

Also, inflating this would be other option but for now..can I do something abt this?

Thanks for reading.. :)

Comment: Please share the code you used to add the LinearLayout to the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory it goes like this:

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
scroll.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(yourLinearLayout);
```

sO basically just put you linearLayout to ScrollView and set it as dialogView in the end like,

```
alertDialog.setView(scroll);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `<ScrollView ></ScrollView>` to wrap your layout.